# MongoDB: how to say Mongo to save insert update in my local json files

Tags: mongodb

I have two json files in directory c:\test. I would like to use them as collection in MongoDB.

that files called companies.json and clients.json.

when i do `db.clients.insert` (in client mongo) , I would like data save automatically in clients.json.

If I do an update the same.

Is it possible?

Comment: MongoDB doesn't store data in JSON format. If you have to store and update local JSON file, your best bet is some programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not store data as JSON, nor as any human-readable format.

Depending on why you're asking, you could use [`mongoexport`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) to make JSON dumps of your database.

Comment: I was reading and speaking with mongodb experts today, they told the same